# Powershell -ErrorAction not working for Receive-File

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have created the utility to upload files using `Receive-File`. It's working fine however if user missed to choose the file and clicks **OK** button in that case I am getting the error message popup.

I have tried try and catch but code not getting inside the catch and I tried `-ErrorAction Stop` but that as well not working again getting an error popup. I have tried the `Continue` & `SilentlyContinue` values in the `-ErrorAction` but still error message popup appears.
Does anyone have a clue how to stop showing the error message popup and continue the code?

the below is the code for your reference

```
$dataFolder = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::DataFolder
$tempFolder = $dataFolder + "\tempupload" 
try
{
$filePath = Receive-File -Path $tempFolder  -Description "Upload your content file" -Title "Upload Utility" -CancelButtonName "Cancel" -OkButtonName "Ok" -overwrite  -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: What version of SPE are you using? I'm testing with 6.2 and I see a validation message when clicking OK without selecting a file.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am using SPE Version  5.0.0.42513 Thanks!!

Comment: What error are you seeing ? Did you check this ? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/okclick-method-through-reflection-is-not-allowed-error-with-spe