# Broken error message within PowerShell Receive-File dialog. Sitecore XP 10.1.2 (rev. 006578)

Tags: powershell

I have a simple powershell script that invokes file upload into the context item:

`Receive-File -ParentItem (get-item .)`

If I try to upload existing file (name of the item exists in the same folder) it should show the warning message. This message is shown if I just use Upload File interface of Content Editor.
But in my case, the dialog box is broken and there is a JS error in console:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: scForm is not defined*

[image]

I was not able to find any similar reports but it is reproducible on my local env and on Azure as well. Sitecore XP 10.1.2 (rev. 006578)

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Can you try the solution given by Michael West in this thread? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/okclick-method-through-reflection-is-not-allowed-error-with-spe

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding Overwrite option to the receive-file command as below.

```
Receive-File -ParentItem (get-item .) -Overwrite
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thing is that I do not need to allow overwrites. I need to show a message to a user that item already exists

Comment: Reason for the error is duplicate file names are prevented on the same level. You can modify the OnLoad method inside  Spe.Client.Applications.UploadFile.PowerShellUploadFilePage2 to achieve the same.

Comment: My issue is not the error, but the broken error popup